ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API - can't publish on IIS after adding authentication
Created a sample ASP.Net Core WeatherForecast Web API and Deployed on IIS (which is running on local machine), and it is working as expected no issue at all.
Once I added authorization in program.cs I m getting HTTP Error 500 at the time of publishing.
program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch;
using Serilog.Sinks.File;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {        
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
            (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Secret"])),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


appsettings.Development.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionInMemory": "Server=Server1;Database=DB1;Trusted_Connection=True;",   
  },
  "JwtSettings": {
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:8082",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:8082",
    "Secret": "e018128191ae4c45ad2dff4eb9aab4e8de9ac0946efd7c822b3f165ef5a9bf3d",
    "TokenValidityInMinutes": 15,
    "RefreshTokenValidityInDays": 7
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs/logs-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Elasticsearch",
        "Args": {
          "nodeUris": "elksrv:9200",
          "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
          "indexFormat": "Adept_Unity-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "UseInMemoryDatabase": false
}

I have also installed the Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting Bundle File on the IIS Server
Deployment steps:
Publishing directly from visual studio.
IIS Profile :
Configuration : Release
Target Framework : net8.0
Deployment Mode : Framework-dependent
Target Runtime : Portable
Below are the logs from event viewer. Getting below 3 logs entries right after deployment failed.
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\weather' was recycled after detecting app_offline.htm
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WEATHER' has shutdown.
the above two at the same time.
this entry after 5 seconds delay.
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\weather' started successfully.
Any help would be great :)

What's the 500 error details error message? Besides, I suggest you could put the configuration from the appsettings.Development.json to the appsettings.json.

Please check full error message on the server first. 500 internal error means a lot.

Issue resolved, there was something wrong with the application pool, deleted and created and started working.
